# Car Bank1 O2 Sensor Query

Tags: yaris, vitz

Car Yaris/Vitz, engine 1sz-fe, automatic
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking it looks fine. It looks as though the vehicle is in "Open Loop" during the first little bit, then goes into "Closed Loop" when you see all the activity. During Open Loop mode, the computer doesn't use O2 sensor, but rather runs a fairly rich mixture so as to heat up the catalytic converter faster. This bears out with the relatively high reading at first. In closed loop, you start seeing the varied signal going quite rapidly from low to high, which is a typical reading for a properly functioning O2.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I was afraid it got faulty. Regards